# How can I group by misspelled records in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm looking for advice on how to tackle the issue of different spelling for the same name. I have a SQL Server database with job positions, and there are some names that are the same but the spelling is different. While using distinct getting like below but all are same position

For example:

- Former Employee - SBM (Student Brand Manager)
- Former Employee - SBM
- Former Employee - Student Brand Manager
- Former Employee - Student Brand Manager (SBM)

Like above lot of records are there, sometimes it's an extra 's', other times its an extra space.

**Note**: these positions are displayed in a drop down how to group by and display and while click that name I want to get all records with out data lost.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you fix the data, rather than work around it ?

Comment: Ultimately you have two choices: (1) fix the data so it consistently reflects the official job title; or (2) create a mapping table (which you manually maintain from time to time) that translates the various unofficial job titles into the official job title, and use this to join an official job title column onto your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would usually create a mapping table to permanently fix this. 
A quick fix that I usually use on query is to write a view like below:

```
Select 
Case when [Job Position] like '%Former Employee - SBM%' OR [Job Position] like '%Former Employee - Student Brand Manager%'
THEN 'SBM'
ELSE [Job Position] END as 'Job Position'
,[Field 2], [Field 3], ...

FROM TABLENAME
```

OR

```
Select 
Case when [Job Position] in ('Former Employee - SBM (Student Brand Manager)','Former Employee - SBM','Former Employee - Student Brand Manager','Former Employee - Student Brand Manager (SBM)')
THEN 'SBM'
ELSE [Job Position] END as 'Job Position'
,[Field 2], [Field 3], ...

FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Not exact solution somewhat better to rectify my issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is a hard problem.

My recommendation is to start with a list of all distinct job positions:

```
select distinct job_position
from t;
```

Then, load this into a spreadsheet and manually put in the official name.  Then load this back into the database, and use it when updating and inserting the job position -- if a position is not in the table, then reject it.

You can then join to the table to get the official version.

Answer (score 1):

Not that it would be recommended, but you should also be able to group by a result of changed values such as:

```
group by (CASE WHEN name like 'SBM%' or name like 'Student Brand Manager%' THEN 'SBM' END)
```

The same decode needs to appear in the Select statement as well (if you want to see the name)

Comment: Here a sql fiddle: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a41ddd142f8dccf39fc03bf2cbab12b